# What is Open Radio Access Network?

Tags: network, access-point, network-access

what is the concept of this open radio access networks?? more specifically what is this "open" for? how is it different from those of general RAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A radio access network (RAN) is part of a mobile telecommunication system. It implements a radio access technology. Conceptually, it resides between a device such as a mobile phone, a computer, or any remotely controlled machine and provides connection with its core network (CN). Depending on the standard, mobile phones and other wireless connected devices are varyingly known as user equipment (UE), terminal equipment, mobile station (MS), etc. RAN functionality is typically provided by a silicon chip residing in both the core network as well as the user equipments* [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_access_network)

O-RAN – is an open RAN network meaning that any vendor’s equipment would work on any part of the network regardless of whose core was managing the network.

Open, standards-based network architectures with interoperable interfaces and off-the-shelf components enable mobile operators to address a diverse set of demands in support of new vertical market revenue opportunities.[Click Here](https://wade4wireless.com/2018/07/05/what-are-open-ran-systems-pros-and-cons/)

simply OpenRAN is an initiative to define and build 2G, 3G and 4G RAN solutions based on a general-purpose vendor-neutral hardware and software-defined technology.[Click Here](https://openran.telecominfraproject.com/)